# Confused about How can i make mymenu run

Tags: android

I  am trying to learn how to use a  menu in android I have just added few subitems inside menu.xml file .And run it .In the console in everything seems normal but when i check logcat a lot of errors shows up.I have no idea what is wrong I cant figure it out with my 5 days android programing expresience.Can you please help.Thank is advance

```
02-15 05:13:04.420: E/logwrapper(912): executing /system/bin/e2fsck failed: No such file or directory
02-15 05:13:04.440: E/logwrapper(915): executing /system/bin/e2fsck failed: No such file or directory
02-15 05:13:05.010: E/SurfaceFlinger(923): hwcomposer module not found
02-15 05:13:05.820: E/SurfaceFlinger(923): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
02-15 05:13:08.240: E/logwrapper(1175): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
02-15 05:13:08.240: E/logwrapper(1176): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
02-15 05:13:19.410: E/FlpHardwareProvider(1251): Error hw_get_module 'flp': -2
02-15 05:13:19.410: E/FlpHardwareProvider(1251): Error hw_get_module 'flp': -2
02-15 05:13:19.410: E/LocationManagerService(1251): no geocoder provider found
02-15 05:13:19.410: E/LocationManagerService(1251): No FusedProvider found.
02-15 05:13:19.410: E/LocationManagerService(1251): no geofence provider found
02-15 05:13:25.100: E/Netd(920): exec() res=0, status=256 for /system/bin/iptables -t mangle -A st_mangle_EXEMPT -d 10.0.2.4/32 -j MARK --set-mark 1 
02-15 05:13:25.100: E/logwrapper(1561): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
02-15 05:13:25.100: E/logwrapper(1562): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
02-15 05:13:25.100: E/SecondaryTablController(920): ip route add failed: /system/bin/ip route add 10.0.2.2/32 via 0.0.0.0 dev eth0 table 60
02-15 05:13:25.100: E/ConnectivityService(1251): Exception trying to add a route: java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '16 interface fwmark exempt add 10.0.2.2/32' failed with '400 16 Failed to add exemption rule (File exists)'
02-15 05:13:37.460: E/StrictMode(1693):     at com.android.mms.transaction.TransactionService.onNewIntent(TransactionService.java:224)
02-15 05:13:37.460: E/StrictMode(1693):     at com.android.mms.transaction.TransactionService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(TransactionService.java:621)
02-15 05:13:37.460: E/StrictMode(1693):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-15 05:13:37.460: E/StrictMode(1693):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
: E/(): Device disconnected


<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
```

this the rest of my code

```
</menu>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">mymenu</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
      <string name="MenuItem">Open</string>
    <string />

</resources>

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does it run correctly?

Comment: I think so.Because.everything looks normal in the console screen and emulator launched properly and I am able to see Helloworld Textview also But there is no menu  anywhere.I have no idea what line are important and need to be filtred .So this a little part of errors

Comment: Did you press the menu button?

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure the menu item is properly declared in the xml menu file.
2. Ensure that you have included `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`. And have inflated the appropriate menu in there.
3. Ensure you have included `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` and check for the corresponding MenuItem IDs.

Comment: I have added all the code.Is there anything wrong here

Comment: In your menu folder you need to have a menu layout, which has something like:     
<item
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/add"/>
in it. There are quite a few steps and it is hard for me to explain everything on here, I think it might be a good idea for you to check out some tutorials using the action bar, there are some pretty good ones on youtube, or you can just check out the documentation. Btw it is convention to accept an answer if it has helped you.